# Can't delete the cookies of users in nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, cookies

In my nodejs application, I have a delete selected users logic. This simply takes the selected users `ids` sent by the admin of the application via reactjs, this can be anything from 2 and above users. I now thought about it what if the users selected to be deleted are loggged in. Like they are using the app as at when the admin wants to delete them? I used this code normally to delete cookies when a user wants to logout or delete his or her account:

```
const cookies = req.cookies;
 res.clearCookie('refreshJWT', {httpOnly: true});
```

When I applied this same code while deleting selected users, it didn't work because it was producing the cookies of the admin. Is there a way to get the cookies of the selected users and not the cookies of the admin? Or should I go ahead and delete the users leaving their cookies? It is a MERN stack application which I am building to learn the entire stack.

Comment: Your user have to first make a request to remove their cookies

Comment: But this logic is for the admin to delete them from the application. The users aren't the ones who want to delete them selves. Is there a way around this?